# Capitalization after an ellipsis beginning a paragraph midway in a multi-paragraph quotation

Tags: capitalization, ellipses, citation, omissibility

If midway in a multi-paragraph quotation, a paragraph begins with one or more prior paragraphs omitted, and the line starts mid-sentence with preceding words omitted, is the line capitalized after the ellipsis?

*Chicago Manual of Style* advises no ellipsis at the start of a quotation, I'm aware, but what of the case of a subsequent paragraph, preceded by an omission, in a long quotation?

CMOS §13.56, "Ellipses for the omission of whole or partial paragraphs," provides an example illustrating two ellipses in a row (one at the end of a paragraph, one at the start) from Alexander Pope’s *Letter to a Noble Lord*:

"Were it the mere excess of your Lordship’s wit, that carried you thus triumphantly over all the bounds of decency, I might consider your Lordship on your Pegasus, as a sprightly hunter on a mettled horse. . . .

". . . Unrivalled as you are, in making a figure, and in making a speech, methinks, my Lord, you may well give up the poor talent of making a distich."

However, in this case, reading the original [here](https://archive.org/details/worksofalexander05popeuoft/page/424/mode/2up?q=%22Unrivalled%20as%20you%20are%22), the second ellipsis comes before a complete sentence. What if the omission and start of the new paragraph began mid-sentence:

". . . methinks, my Lord, you may well give up the poor talent of making a distich."

Would "methinks" then be capitalized?

Answer (score 1):

[Craig Shrives, in Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_ellipsis_three_dots.htm), possibly as reasonable a source as any hereabouts, and using the format I would, renders (example taken from the Ralph Waldo Emerson quotation)

- *Do not go where the path may lead, go instead where there is no path and leave a trail.*

as

- *... go ... where there is no path and leave a trail.*

However, APA, like CMOS, apparently advises:

> [D]o not include ellipses at the beginning or end of quotes, just for
> content you remove from the middle of the quotation.

[[from Antioch.edu](https://www.antioch.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Tips-for-Modifying-Quotes.pdf)]

It probably expects capitalisation (perhaps *[G]o ... where there is no path and leave a trail*) especially if there is no preceding dialogue tag in a sentence, and an ellipsis to show omitted sentences.

Comment: Thanks, but why is the first ellipsis omitted in your example of "[G]o ... where there is no path and leave a trail."? Just to be clear, the question concerns the mid-sentence start of a new paragraph after a preceding one.

Comment: The examples in the above answer do not deal with a multi-paragraph example where an ellipsis represents omission in the area I'm inquiring about.

Comment: With your example, capitalising in square brackets is universally acknowledged as an edited switch from lower-case. I'd probably add more than one ellipsis to show a sizeable omission, and as the continuation stands alone (in this case) as a sentence, capitalise using the square brackets. But different editors may have other ideas; ELU points out but does not prescribe different style choices.